# Connect to my home PC from my Work PC where remote RDP is blocked

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop, proxy

I have a home PC where I enabled remote desktop connection, It's working (I'm able to connect via my smartphone using external network), but on my Work PC which use the company Network I wasn't able to connect via RDP since as usual many Protocols/Ports are blocked on corporate Networks, The only thing I think of is something over the web/HTTP since we have a private HTTP Proxy that we use to connect to internet.

Does anyone know a solution that might help ?

What I've tried :

- Windows 7 Remote Desktop connection as a client
- Chrome remote Desktop (their new Web app also)

P.S:I'm not attempting to bypass rules of out IT team, I just want to know if there is away to achieve what I want to do without breaking any restrictions (per example if there is a web solution so I will not break their restriction since the purpose of these restriction is maintaining security ..)

Answer (score 1):

Change port where rdp listens to 'it is small registry editing' and try to use allowed port on your company firewall eg 80,443,25,110,465 etc

Also this will only work for firewall based filtering. In case of activity filtering the whole protocol could be blocked. To bypass this you will need to find vpn protocol allowed on filter and use it to bypass filter.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using good old fashioned TeamViewer?

And maybe if SSH isnt blocked, maybe you can setup an SSH Tunnel to do it?

Comment: SSH Tunnel is the best option I Guess if SSH is not blocked either.
What where SSH is blocked ? maybe web based rdp ?

Answer (score 0):

As a Security Administrator, I'm pretty sure that if your organization blocks outbound RDP connections it's because they do not want anyone connecting to systems outside the organisation from within. Maybe standard SSH, VNC, Telnet, etc. ports and protocols are also blocked in the same way for the same reason.

Right now, if you're trying to do something your company doesn't allow, you're infringing their rules, and I wouldn't do that if I were you.